# Pandas: Find original index of a value with a grouped dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with a `RangeIndex`, timestamps in the first column and several thousands hourly temperature observations in the second.

It is easy enough to group the observations by 24 and find daily Tmax and Tmin. But I also want the timestamp of each day's max and min values.

How can I do that?

I hope I can get help without posting a working example, because the nature of the data makes it unpractical.

EDIT: Here's some data, spanning two days.

```
        DT                      T-C
    0   2015-01-01 00:00:00     -2.5
    1   2015-01-01 01:00:00     -2.1
    2   2015-01-01 02:00:00     -2.3
    3   2015-01-01 03:00:00     -2.3
    4   2015-01-01 04:00:00     -2.3
    5   2015-01-01 05:00:00     -2.0
   ...
    24  2015-01-02 00:00:00     1.1
    25  2015-01-02 01:00:00     1.1
    26  2015-01-02 02:00:00     0.8
    27  2015-01-02 03:00:00     0.5
    28  2015-01-02 04:00:00     1.0
    29  2015-01-02 05:00:00     0.7
```

Comment: Can you add first 5 rows of data to question?

Answer (score 1):

First create `DatetimeIndex`, then aggregate by [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) with `days` and [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html)
[`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for datetimes for `min` and `max` temperature:

```
df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'])
df = df.set_index('DT')

df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['T-C'].agg(['idxmax','idxmin','max','min'])
print (df)
                        idxmax              idxmin  max  min
DT                                                          
2015-01-01 2015-01-01 05:00:00 2015-01-01 00:00:00 -2.0 -2.5
2015-01-02 2015-01-02 00:00:00 2015-01-02 03:00:00  1.1  0.5
```

Comment: So, first I need to change the inded so it will become the list of my timestamp values?

Comment: @FabioCapezzuoli - Yes, exactly.